# Source code WebBrowser

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I want to know how to find the source code of the website I went to in my program using WebBrowser. I have this code but it opens up a new window and I want the text to go in the richtextbox.

```
    Form sourceForm = new Form();
    TextBox sourceCode = new TextBox();
    sourceCode.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    sourceCode.Multiline = true;
    sourceCode.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
    sourceForm.Width = 700;
    sourceForm.Height = 500;
    sourceForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    sourceForm.ShowIcon = false;
    sourceForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    sourceForm.Text = "Source Code for " + WebBrowser.Url;
    sourceCode.Text = WebBrowser.DocumentText;
    sourceForm.Controls.Add(sourceCode);
    sourceForm.Show(this);
    sourceCode.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: If you create a  new form then it will show in new window. Add the sourceCode into existing form using this. this.Controles.Add(sourceCode).

Comment: Sorry did not quite understand
You can register the revised code please?

Comment: where have you written this code. Which event ? which class?

Comment: I found this code online I put it in a timer and I want every time Lattimer load the source code of the site I found it in WebBrowser to riechtextbox

Comment: Then there is no need to create a new form and new text box every time just have  textbox in the current form and sets its Text propoerty.You can create the text box in Load event of the form.

Comment: Could you give me a code please I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Paste the whole code this form.

Comment: What code: X?
Sorry maybe I did not quite understand my English is not good